# PHP Gregwar/Formidable alternative on NodeJS?

Tags: php, node.js, forms

I just use https://github.com/Gregwar/Formidable before and it works perfectly for me. But I can't find the alternative library in NodeJS.

Please help me.

---

The `Gregwar/Formidable` is a library that parses HTML form tag to an object which contains form data. So we can get token, default value,... from that form, modify that and post to form url. So, we can use that to easily fake user actions on the web.

---

For example:

```
let theForm = `<form action="/abc">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="123456"/>
<select name="name">
   <option value="selected" selected>TEST</option>
   <option value="notselected">TEST</option>
</select>
</form>`;

parseForm(theForm)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data); // {token: 123456, name: 'selected'}
    });
```

I want a lib that can get value of the html form like parseForm function.

Comment: Asking for recommendations on libraries is off-topic here. If you wanted to create sth. like this yourself, then I’d start with a DOM parser ... and after that, you would have to implement all the steps of the form submission algorithm to determine which data would actually get send if this form was submitted ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of working, I found this lib that can solve my answer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-parse

Thank you for supporting

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Formidable but as far as I check out quickly, it is providing an easy accessibility to your form values in your PHP code.

The answer of node is [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) It is around for a long time and dependent by lots of api and applications

Comment: That's not the library I want. I just add an example for more understandably.

Comment: That JSON you mentioned in your code is req.body when you use body-parser. First check out body-parser.

Comment: @Volem I think they want to parse the given _HTML code_ of a form, and extract the parameters and values that it _would_ send if it was submitted ...